# Winforms Location

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an app with 2 `forms`, the main window and a second `Form`.

What I want is to open up the second `Form` on a `button click` and it's location must be right beside the main form *(so if the main form is `600px` wide, the `X` of the new `Form` will be `main.X + 600`)*

Have tried this but it doesn't seem to take, it opens on top of the main form still:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form = new SecondForm();
    var main = this.Location;
    form.Location = new Point((main.X + 600), main.Y);
    form.Show(); 
}
```

Is `Location` not the correct attribute?

Comment: have you looked at using the DesktopLocation Property..?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It is better to use `this.Width` instead of a hardcoding value (600).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set your form's `StartPosition` to `FormStartPosition.Manual`. You can do it in the designer or from the constructor:

```
StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

Answer (score 5):

`Location` is right property, but you must set

```
Form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

too.

Comment: Yes I was missing this. Thanks

Comment: For some reason setting the Location of the new form to `(this.Size.Width,this.Location,Y)` does not open the new form exactly on the right edge of the old form but still overlays it somewhat. Offsetting the X value doesn't seem to change it

Comment: @sd_dracula you need `(this.Location.X + this.Size.Width,this.Location.Y)` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Clearly you didn't count on the StartPosition property.  Changing it to Manual is however not the correct fix, the second form you load may well rescale itself on another machine with a different video DPI setting.  Very common these days.  Which in turn can change its Location property.

The proper way is wait for the Load event to fire, rescaling is done by then and the window is not yet visible.  Which is the best time to move it in the right place.  StartPosition no longer matters now.  Like this:

```
        var frm = new SecondForm();
        frm.Load += delegate {
            frm.Location = new Point(this.Right, this.Top);
        };
        frm.Show();
```