# Spread multiple instances of the same form over screen in c#

Tags: c#

Is it possible in c# to spread multiple instances of the same form?
Say i had this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
            Form myForm = new Form();
            myForm.Show();
}
```

and I wanted to spread these 10 windows across the screen in random locations. How would i do that? Please respond with some code that i can use. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you kinda said it already. You set their positions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296137/winforms-location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a random generator like `Random` and set the `Location` of the windows:

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    Form myform = new Form();
    int x = random.Next(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width);
    int y = random.Next(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    myForm.Location = new Point(x, y);
    myForm.Show();
}
```

Points to note:

- be sure to instantiate `Random` outisde the loop, otherwise you always get a new instance with the same seed, resulting in always the same position
- decide if `Screen.PrimaryScreen` is ok for you or if you have to deal with mutliple screens (which would be an extra topic)
- you obviously might want to substract something from `Width` and `Height`, otherwise you may get windows with the upper left corner to the right or below the screen:

Example:

```
int x = random.Next(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - myForm.Width);
int y = random.Next(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - myForm.Height);
```